# Loading many resources in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to load resources from isolate?

There are a lot of resources in my app.
They take a very long time to load and UI is freeze.

I have made loading via "compute" function, but I get such crash at line `await rootBundle.load(path);`

> _CompileTimeError (error: native function 'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found)

I also tried to pass AssetBundle as parameter to "compute" function, but also received a crash.

How to make loading resources faster and more effective?

Comment: better to include more code, so we can reproduce your error...